# Instagram API $data returning NULL

Tags: php, json, instagram-api

I am trying to display my instagram followers counts in a custom PHP file.

I am trying this code:

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/280766222/media/recent/?access_token=$token';
$content      =   file_get_contents($url);
$data         =   json_decode($content, true);
var_dump($data['data']);
?>
```

It only returns `NULL`.

What should I do?

Comment: What does: `echo json_last_error_msg();` give you?

Comment: Output `$content` and see what it's returning to you. Instagram made API changes recently that likely broke your app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if `$token` is just a placeholder to hide sensitive information, but if not, you have to pass your personal access token via the URL instead of `$token`:

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/280766222/media/recent/?access_token=$token';
```

You will have to retrieve this token first via the oAuth authentication flow as described [in the Instagram API docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

Answer (score 0):

do you have authorize your access token scope?? if no, you must activate the authorize here : 
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&response_type=token&scope=follower_list